# Reading PCI config space in OS X / Darwin KEXTs

Tags: macos, driver, device-driver, iokit, darwin

In Linux or Windows, one can read the PCI config space of a device from an *arbitrary* driver (not necessarily the one "owning" that particular PCI device). On Linux, one can do it via pci_read_config_*().

Is there any way of doing this from a KEXT for OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IOKit class `IOPCIDevice`, of which there is one for every PCI/Thunderbolt device in the system, has a bunch of [`configRead*` functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Kernel/Reference/IOPCIDevice_reference/#//apple_ref/cpp/instm/IOPCIDevice/configRead32/UInt32) for this purpose. You don't have to have exclusive access (with `open()`) to the instance to do this.